# Angular Reactive Forms - Best way to implement input components wrappers?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

**The task I am trying to solve:**

*Create re-usable input component wrappers to save time when writing template for forms.*

**Example of what I mean:**

Instead of having to write the following template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field> 
<form>
```

I would like to write:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <my-input-component [form]="myForm" [myFormControl]="email" [myFormControlName]="'email'" [label]="'Email'"></my-input-component>
</form>
```

Where **my-input-component** looks like:

```html
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="form">
    <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        [attr.inputmode]="inputMode"
        [placeholder]="label"
        [formControlName]="myFormControlName"
    />
    <mat-error class="errors" *ngIf="myFormControl.invalid">
        <div>{{ getError() }}</div>
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is working as is but I don't know if this is a good approach to pass the FormGroup and FormControls around as bindings.

After searching online I have continuously come across **NG_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR** and was a bit confused if that could or should be used in my scenario.

I don't intend for these components to be "custom" in the sense of using a slider as a form control or something of that nature, but rather just wanted "wrappers" to save some time.

Any suggestions or advice on the topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Idk, doesn't look like it's providing a ton of benefit given the complexity of passing things around and the markup. Plus, `getErrorMessage()` is a contract not explicitly defined or enforced as far as I can see; that's problematic IMHO. Considering there's a finite set of input types you'll have to deal with, have you considered making an `EmailInputComponent` for example that can be used in an obvious way by anyone needing an email input type?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils
You're correct about `getErrorMessage()`, my thought was that this function inside would cover any validation type that would be applied (would have a default case for one-offs).

Also, my intention is to have a few of these wrappers, one for each common type e.g. text input, number input, select dropdown, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to achieve this is, like you have already found out, to implement the [`ControlValueAccessor` interface](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). This interface was created specifically to create custom form controls. It will create a bridge between your reusable component and the Forms API.

Here's a small example of a reusable input field with a label. You could add your error messages in this template as well.

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Self, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.css']
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string = '';
  @Input() type: 'text' | 'email' | 'password' = 'text';

  value: any = '';

  constructor(
    // Retrieve the dependency only from the local injector,
    // not from parent or ancestors.
    @Self()
    // We want to be able to use the component without a form,
    // so we mark the dependency as optional.
    @Optional()
    private ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  /**
   * Write form value to the DOM element (model => view)
   */
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }

  /**
   * Write form disabled state to the DOM element (model => view)
   */
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  /**
   * Update form when DOM element value changes (view => model)
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    // Store the provided function as an internal method.
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  /**
   * Update form when DOM element is blurred (view => model)
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    // Store the provided function as an internal method.
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  private onChange() {}
  private onTouched() {}
}
```

**Template**

```
<label>{{ value }}</label>
<input [type]="type"
       [placeholder]="placeholder"
       [value]="value"
       [disabled]="disabled"
       (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
       (blur)="onTouched()" />
```

You can check out this article [Creating a custom form component in Angular](https://ritchiejacobs.be/angular-custom-form-component) for  more detailed information.